# Getting random Permission Denied errors when accessing from ExternalFilesDir

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I am using NanoHTTPD to serve files to a WebView and getting random Permission denied error on some files.

This happens rarely and not on specific files, and I have observed even outside of this function. 
It looks like an android bug, since the permission denial can happen to a single file in a folder of multiple files.

The folders are are stored in getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).

```
private InputStream loadResourceStream(String uri) {
      File initialFile = new File(uri);
      InputStream targetStream = null;
      try {
          targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          logNonFatalError(e);
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return targetStream;
}
```

The error is thrown in line 
`targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);`

Comment: Do you close the stream at some point in your main program ?

Comment: @Eehol, you are right, I added the close() call now, I hope it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to save file then you should ask run time permission for Write file in storage.

Comment: As stated here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String) Starting in Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling application.

Comment: If you using below api level 23  then it's ok just write in manifests. @Paris S